# Bootstrap carousel not working . It's not sliding?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am not sure why the below does not work. I'm currently doing a web development course on udemy. I tried to apply a carousel with controls, but it does not seem to work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="testimonials">
        <div id="carousel-testimonials" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
              <img class="dog-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
              <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
            </div>
    
            <div class="carousel-item ">
              <h2 id="testimonial-text" class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of
                their
                life. I think.</h2>
              <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
              <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-testimonials" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-testimonials" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working a Example from the Bootstrap website. Hope this helps you. Just change the SRC to the image you wish!

I have done this in Bootstrap 5 since it is the latest. See below your example fixed in Bootstrap 4. Possibly you left out the JS includes.
Hope this helps!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>StackOverflow</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.0.2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <p>Item 1</p>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360
                " class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <p>Item 2</p>

                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360
                " class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <p>Item 3</p>

                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360
                " class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Using Bootstrap 4 and your code;

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="testimonials">
    <div id="carousel-testimonials" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <h2>Slide 1</h2>
                <img class="dog-image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360
                " alt="dog-profile">
                <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item ">
                <h2 id="testimonial-text" class="testimonial-text">Slide 2</h2>
                <img class="testimonial-image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360
                " alt="lady-profile">
                <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-testimonials" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-testimonials" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

4 carousel with control example try replacing the content and img. Hopefully this will work also ensure to link the bootstrap-4 cdn in the script tag :)

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div> <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
</div>
```